# How can I prove the derivative of the following formula?

Tags: derivatives

I have been given the primitive function:

$$F(x) = x^2 \left(4x^2-2\right)^3+5$$

And I must prove that the derivative of $F(x)$ is

$$f(x)=\left(32x^3-4x\right)\left(4x^2-2\right)^2$$

I don't seem to get to the same derivative as I was given with f(x).

Comment: just use the chain rule and the product rule.

Comment: Yes, well I did, but I don't get to the same answer

Comment: What answer did you get?

Comment: F'(x)= 2x(4x^2-2)^3 + x^2 *3(4x^2-2)^2 *8x

That is what I have got from the product and chain rule.

But when I put this all together I will not get the same answer

Comment: That expression is correct, and it simplifies to the given form.  Just factor out the common term of $(4x^2-2)^2$.

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend learning how to format for this site.  I edited your post, but you'll get a better response if you learn how to typeset yourself.  [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial.

Comment: Yes, thank you again. I will definetely look in to it soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the basic step right. It's the simplification that got you all muddled up. So I'll just start from where you stopped and simplify further:

$$F'(x)= 2x(4x^2-2)^3 + x^2 *3(4x^2-2)^2 *8x$$

Factorising out $(4x^2-2)^2$:

$$F'(x)= (4x^2-2)^2[2x(4x^2-2) + x^2 *3 *8x]$$

This gives:

$$F'(x)= (4x^2-2)^2[8x^3-4x + 24x^3]$$

Thus
$$f(x)=F'(x)= (4x^2-2)^2(32x^3-4x)$$

Comment: Ah I see! thanks a lot. This makes sense to me, but how should I have known that I had to factorise out (4x^2-2)? I wouldn't have guessed it on an exam

Comment: Well, that's where you have to improvise. In this case, the derivative had $(4x^2-2)^2$ as a factor thus immediately I  noticed it was a common factor, I simply factorised it out and simplified further.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
F'(x)&=(x^2(4x^2-2)^3)'+(5)'\\
&=(x^2)'(4x^2-2)^3+x^2((4x^2-2)^3)'+0\\
&=2x(4x^2-2)^3+x^23(4x^2-2)^2(4x^2-3)'\\
&=2x(4x^2-2)^3+x^23(4x^2-2)^28x\\
&=(4x^2-2)^2(2x(4x^2-2)+24x^3)\\
&=(4x^2-2)^2(8x^3-4x+24x^3)\\
&=(4x^2-2)^2(32x^3-4x)\\
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT, use:

1. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{b}\left(x\right)+\text{c}\left(x\right)\right)=\text{b}'\left(x\right)+\text{c}'\left(x\right)$$
2. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{g}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{h}\left(x\right)\right)=\text{g}'\left(x\right)\cdot\text{h}\left(x\right)+\text{g}\left(x\right)\cdot\text{h}'\left(x\right)$$
3. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{q}\left(x\right)^\text{n}\right)=\text{n}\text{q}'\left(x\right)\text{q}\left(x\right)^{\text{n}-1}$$
4. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\left(\text{k}\left(x\right)+\text{p}\left(x\right)\right)^\text{n}\right)=\text{n}\left(\text{k}\left(x\right)+\text{p}\left(x\right)\right)^{\text{n}-1}\left(\text{k}'\left(x\right)+\text{p}'\left(x\right)\right)$$
5. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^\text{n}\right)=\text{n}x^{\text{n}-1}$$
6. $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)=1$$
7. When $\text{n}$ is a constant:
   $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{n}\right)=0$$